# How to delete the complex numbers which are generated in a list of numbers?

Tags: random

Here I have generated a list of numbers

```
A3 = (c14^2 s13^2 Exp[-2 I \[Delta]13]) /. {{c14 -> 0.9986}, {c14 ->1}} /. {{s13 -> 0.1434}, {s13 -> 0.1560}} /. {{\[Delta]13 -> 0}, {\[Delta]13 -> 360}}
```

```
{{{0.020506, 0.0205636}, {0.0242679,0.024336}}, {{-0.0172053 + 0.0111567 I, -0.0172536 + 
    0.0111881 I}, {-0.0203617 + 0.0132035 I, -0.0204188 + 0.0132405 I}}}
```

Here in the list I want to delete the complex numbers which are generated. Please suggest how to do it.

Comment: Deleting complex numbers vs. deleting the imaginary parts of complex numbers are two different things. Which one is it? I write this after reading your comment to the answer submitted by @rowsi.

Answer (score 3):

Another way, using `DeleteCases` and `FlattenAt`:

```
FlattenAt[DeleteCases[alist, {__Complex}, 2], {2}]

(*{{{0.020506, 0.0205636}, {0.0242679, 0.024336}}}*)
```

Or using `Cases`:

```
List@Cases[alist, {__Real}, 2]

 (*{{{0.020506, 0.0205636}, {0.0242679, 0.024336}}}*)
```

Or using `GroupBy` and `Lookup`:

```
Lookup[GroupBy[alist, FreeQ[#, Complex] &], True]

(*(*{{{0.020506, 0.0205636}, {0.0242679, 0.024336}}}*)*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
alist = {{{0.020506, 0.0205636}, {0.0242679, 
    0.024336}}, {{-0.0172053 + 0.0111567 I, -0.0172536 + 
     0.0111881 I}, {-0.0203617 + 0.0132035 I, -0.0204188 + 
     0.0132405 I}}};

Delete[alist, Position[alist, _Complex]] /. {{} ..} :> Nothing
```

{{{0.020506, 0.0205636}, {0.0242679, 0.024336}}}

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the real part of your complex numbers, try `Re`:

```
Re@A3
(*{{{0.020506, 0.0205636}, {0.0242679, 
   0.024336}}, {{-0.0172053, -0.0172536}, {-0.0203617, -0.0204188}}}*)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It really worked

Answer (score 1):

Rather than "deleting the complex numbers" you can think of it as "selecting the real numbers". Hence

```
Select[A3, # \[Element] Reals &]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since V. 13.3 there is `RealValuedNumericQ` and `RealValuedNumberQ`. Both filter out complex numbers and non-numeric elements:

```
list = {
   {0.2, 0.4},
   {Pi, 1},
   {13/8, 0.5},
   {-0.1 + 0.2 I, -0.3 + 0.4 I},
   {-1 + I, Complex[1, 1]},
   {Missing[], ComplexInfinity},
   {"A", "B"}};

Cases[list, {__?RealValuedNumericQ}, 2]
```

{{0.2, 0.4}, {Pi, 1}, {13/8, 0.5}}

```
Cases[list, {__?RealValuedNumberQ}, 2]
```

{{0.2, 0.4}, {13/8, 0.5}}